Copying read only images into output in doxygen 1.11.0
I have been generating documentation using doxygen 1.8.20. Recently, we upgraded to 1.11.0.
However, this is generating error messages when a document being parsed by doxygen includes a read-only image. For some reason, this produces the following types of error messages:
error : could not copy file /path_to_source_images/images/an_image.png to /path_to_output/html/an_image.png
Note that the path_to_output folder is first deleted before beginning the doxygen documentation generation.
And the image itself in the output folder is indeed read-only.
So, it seems that the doxygen process is trying to write to that image twice (whereas this did not happen in 1.8.20) and the second time is blocked due to the read-only property of the copied file.
Has anyone any knowledge of what could be causing this in 1.11.0 and whether there is some way to fix it / get around it ?

Under Windows I cannot reproduce it though under Cygwin I can reproduce it. I think the only quick ways out that I see is to ignore the warning or set the protection to writable. Would be nice to have an issue for the problem that looks like to be introduced in doxygen version 1.9.2

The original problem should be relatively easy to solve, but I see also a secondary problem and this is when running doxygen twice without cleaning the directory beforehand. In that case the readonly is already present and thus the message will be given anyway, solving this issue will be more complex.

Thanks for the feedback. How do you know it was introduced in 1.9.2 ?

Well probably you cannot, but I had some executables lying around that I could test.
